# A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'dataset2'

Tags: rdlc

i have one asp.net page with 2 reports. one report is working fine. when i run the second one its showing me this error. i have tried many solutions found in the internet. some one please help me with this

my CS code is

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/mainaccount.rdlc");
            mainaccount dsmainaccount = GetData("select TB_MAIN_ACNT_NAME ,TB_MAIN_ACNT_CODE,TB_OP_BAL ,TB_CR_DT ,TB_TXN_DEBIT ,TB_TXN_CREDIT ,TB_CL_BAL_DR ,TB_CL_BAL_CR  FROM FT_TRIALBAL_MPG WHERE TB_COMP_CODE='MCS' and TB_SYS_ID=233");
            ReportDataSource datasourcemain = new ReportDataSource("mainaccount", dsmainaccount.Tables[0]);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasourcemain);
        }
    }

    private mainaccount GetData(string query)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OrionConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query);
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString))
        {
            using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (mainaccount dsmainaccount = new mainaccount())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dsmainaccount, "DataTable2");
                    return dsmainaccount;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my aspx page code is

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
         </head>
        <body>
         <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>                                                       
     <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-                                                                    Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
           WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana"
            WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="mainaccount.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource2" Name="dataset2" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

     <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server"                      SelectMethod="Select" TypeName="trialbalance.mainaccount+DataTable2DataTable">                            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
      <br />
       </div>
</form>
        </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

both reports use the same DataSet?

ReportDataSource datasourcemain = new ReportDataSource("mainaccount",dsmainaccount.Tables[1]);

which is to help the exact error that shows you in the report?

Comment: no 2 datasets for 2 different reports. mainaccount is the dataset for the current report. first report is working fine, wen this code is executed i get the error "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'dataset2'"

Answer (score 0):

then you must fill both dataSet and transfer them to your local reporting , as shown in the following image:

[here model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PON8j.png)